# How to re-initiate tailwind's datepicker when added dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css, flowbite

I am using tailwind's datepicker and I add new items by clicking a button:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <!-- ... -->
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/flowbite@1.5.1/dist/datepicker.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- ... -->
        <input datepicker type="text" placeholder="Select date">
        <button>Add</button>
      <!-- ... -->
      <script>
        document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
          var input = document.createElement('input');
          input.setAttribute('datepicker', '');
          document.body.appendChild(input);

          document.querySelectorAll('[datepicker]').forEach(function(datepickerEl) {
             new Datepicker(datepickerEl, getDatepickerOptions(datepickerEl));
            // ❌ Unhandled Promise Rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Datepicker
          });
        });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Once a new item has been added, it does not have the datepicker. How can I re-initate the datepicker to all new items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in the code -

1. The script that's been imported does not expose `Datepicker` and `Daterangepicker` objects. You will need to replace the import with the correct [script](https://script%20src=%22https://unpkg.com/flowbite-datepicker@1.2.2/dist/js/datepicker-full.js) that exposes the objects.
2. You need to import `flowbite.min.css` and `flowbite.js` for the functionalities to work correctly.
3. Import the `flowbite` scripts before the end of the body tag so your page has loaded before the scripts kick in and scan for `input` tags with `datepicker` or other data-tags.
4. Additionally, I have wrapped your script inside the `ready` function which will execute only after the page has fully loaded or refreshed. Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7053197/1028986).

```html
    <html>
    
    <head>
      <!-- ... -->
    
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flowbite@1.5.3/dist/flowbite.min.css" />
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <!-- ... -->
      <input id="test" datepicker type="text" placeholder="Select date">
      <button>Add</button>
      <script>
    
        function ready(callback){
        // in case the document is already rendered
        if (document.readyState!='loading') callback();
        // modern browsers
        else if (document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback);
        // IE <= 8
        else document.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', function(){
            if (document.readyState=='complete') callback();
        });
    }
    
    ready(function(){
        document.querySelectorAll('[datepicker]').forEach(function (datepickerEl) {
          new window.Datepicker(datepickerEl);
        });
    
        document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
          var input = document.createElement('input');
          input.setAttribute('datepicker', '');
          input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
          document.body.appendChild(input);
    
          new window.Datepicker(input);
        });
    });
      </script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/flowbite@1.5.3/dist/flowbite.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/flowbite-datepicker@1.2.2/dist/js/datepicker-full.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```